# SFML не дружит с WinSock2

Tags: c++, sfml, winsock

Я решил отказаться от SFML Network, и использовать WinSock2. Проблема заключается в том, что если я подключаю WinSock2 (+ использую #pragma warning(disable: 4996)), то компилятор vs 17 начинается жаловаться на ошибки, допущенные в файле rect.inl, который на сколько я понял и является частью sfml библиотеки. При этом в файле подсвечиваются все строчки с Rect и ошибкой "Rect не является шаблоном". Как я могу решить это?

Comment: замените в своем файле Rect на sf::Rect. Должно помочь

Comment: @KoVadim заменил, теперь жалуется на std::min и std::max, из-за "недопустимой лексемы слева". Если убрать std:: - ошибок ещё больше.

Comment: убирать std:: не нужно. Перед включением Winsock.h добавьте `#define NOMINMAX`. Если же Вы включили windows.h - то перед ними обома

Comment: *обома (укр) == обоими

Comment: так я не знаю русского. пользуюсь переводчиком. Иногда не получается

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan Не помогло :(

Comment: у Вас все равно не компилируется или не смогли разобраться?

Comment: @KoVadim , я добавил #define NOMINMAX при объявлении экрана и при включении библиотеки винсок. Ошибка с лексемой не пропала.

Comment: тут ключевой момент - это define должен быть написан "до инклуда winsock". То есть, можно самой первой строкой в файле

Comment: @KoVadim Это поменяло исход компиляции, но теперь с новыми ошибками. https://ibb.co/yqF2jPM

Comment: @KoVadim перевод ошибок с google translator - Посилання на недозволений зовнішній сімбвол

Comment: так это уже проблема линковки, Нужно просто подобавлять нужные библиотеки  sfml.

Comment: @KoVadim Последняя ошибка была исключительно моей виной, т.к. забыл убрать мусор. Теперь всё работает, спасибо огромное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оформлю свои комментарии в виде ответа.

Как только в проект подключается winsock.h, то сразу подключается и windows.h. А это очень тяжелый и "неудобный" заголовок - он несет много много старого груза. К примеру, там есть структруа Rect, которая пересекается с такой же в sfml. Поэтому, используем имена полностью в коде - sf::Rect, а не `using namespace sf;`.

Жалоба на std::min и std::max - это с той же оперы. где-то внутри windows.h есть что то вида

```
#define max(a,b) a>b?a:b
#define min(a,b) a>b?b:a
```

а как известно, препроцессору побоку на namespace и увидев `std::max(1,2)` он просто заменяет на `std::1>2?1:2`, что и срывает крышу плюсовому компилятору и программисту (не так просто сразу увидеть, что это макрос и во что он разворачивается).

К сожалению, просто так убрать это с windows.h нельзя, поэтому придумали обходной маневр - оно там завернуто в `#ifndef NOMINMAX  .. #endif` и добавив `#define NOMINMAX` это дело прячется. Но нужно объявлять до первой встречи с этим include. Иначе это не работает.

P.S. Никогда не добавляйте Windows.h в свои header файлы. Во первых, он очень большой - значит компиляция замедлится, во вторых, там сколько всего, что неизвестно, что ещё может вылезти (к примеру, bind и std::bind).